# Unexpected Keyword argument in django model from json data

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

In my Django project I have a model class having some fields. I have an API endpoint from which I get a JSON response. I parsed the JSON using the requests library and tried to make a model instance. Unfortunately, I could not do so. The following is the stack trace

```
Internal Server Error: /app/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\REVE\PycharmProjects\FantasyFootballAnalytics\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\REVE\PycharmProjects\FantasyFootballAnalytics\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\REVE\PycharmProjects\FantasyFootballAnalytics\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\REVE\PycharmProjects\FantasyFootballAnalytics\app\views.py", line 38, in index
    strength_defence_away=team['strength_defence_away']
  File "C:\Users\REVE\PycharmProjects\FantasyFootballAnalytics\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 501, in __init__
    raise TypeError("%s() got an unexpected keyword argument '%s'" % (cls.__name__, kwarg))
TypeError: Team() got an unexpected keyword argument 'team_code'
```

Here is my model class:

```
class Team(models.Model):

    team_code = models.IntegerField
    draw = models.IntegerField
    # form = models.FloatField(null=True)
    team_id = models.IntegerField
    loss = models.IntegerField
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    played = models.IntegerField
    points = models.IntegerField
    position = models.IntegerField
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    strength = models.IntegerField
    # team_division = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    unavailable = models.BooleanField
    win = models.IntegerField
    strength_overall_home = models.IntegerField
    strength_overall_away = models.IntegerField
    strength_attack_home = models.IntegerField
    strength_attack_away = models.IntegerField
    strength_defence_home = models.IntegerField
    strength_defence_away = models.IntegerField

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here is my view function:

```
def index(request):
    data = requests.get("https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/")

    json = data.json()

    teams = []
    for team in json['teams']:

        new_team = Team(team_code=team['code'],
                    draw=team['draw'],
                    # form=team['form'],
                    team_id=team['id'],
                    loss=team['loss'],
                    name=team['name'],
                    played=team['played'],
                    points=team['points'],
                    position=team['position'],
                    short_name=team['short_name'],
                    strength=team['strength'],
                    # team_division=team['team_division'],
                    unavailable=team['unavailable'],
                    win=team['win'],
                    strength_overall_home=team['strength_overall_home'],
                    strength_overall_away=team['strength_overall_away'],
                    strength_attack_home=team['strength_attack_home'],
                    strength_attack_away=team['strength_attack_away'],
                    strength_defence_home=team['strength_defence_home'],
                    strength_defence_away=team['strength_defence_away']

                    )
            teams.append(new_team)


    Team.objects.bulk_create(teams)
    return JsonResponse({'teams': serializers.serialize('json', Team.objects.all())})
```

The json object I am working on:

```
{'code': 3,
 'draw': 0,
 'form': None,
 'id': 1,
 'loss': 0,
 'name': 'Arsenal',
 'played': 0,
 'points': 0,
 'position': 0,
 'short_name': 'ARS',
 'strength': 4,
 'strength_attack_away': 1270,
 'strength_attack_home': 1240,
 'strength_defence_away': 1330,
 'strength_defence_home': 1290,
 'strength_overall_away': 1330,
 'strength_overall_home': 1250,
 'team_division': None,
 'unavailable': False,
 'win': 0}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: You need to instantiate the model fields: `team_code = models.IntegerField()` or `unavailable = models.BooleanField()`, they should not be classes.

Comment: As a side note, you __really__ want to validate and sanitize your data before using them. Never trust anything coming from the outside world...